# QGIS - cannot change CRS of shapefile

Tags: qgis

I am working with a shapefile that reflects the USDA Plant Hardiness Zones in the U.S. http://prism.oregonstate.edu/projects/public/phm/phm_us_shp.zip

I would like to change the CRS, but have so far been unsuccessful in doing so.  The native CRS is NAD83/ESPG 4269.  Despite repeated attempts to "change" the CRS, the actual display of the map does not change.  As an example, I would like to use ESPG 2163 instead.

Has anyone worked with this shapefile, and have you been able to change the CRS?  If so, I would greatly appreciate it if you could outline the steps you performed in QGIS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGIS easily project or transform CRS of shapefiles. Here is the steps that you must to follow to change CRS of a SHP:

1. Open a new project and add your layer to QGIS.
2. In Layers pane right click the layer and select Export then Save Vector Layer as..

[Export > Save Vector Layer as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jne6j.png)

3. In 'Save Vector Layer as' window, first select format as Shapefile
4. Click the browse button next to filename text box and select where do you save the new file and give it a name.
5. At the end of CRS line, click CRS selector and write 2163 to filter and select "US National Atlas Equal Area, EPSG:2163" in CRS list and click OK.

[CRS Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDoQK.png)

6. Finally click OK and QGIS project your SHP.

[Here is the resulting SHP](https://yadi.sk/d/dDI3UkHgV-_pCw)

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  I was trying to change the CRS by clicking on the properties of the layer and changing it within that.  That was not working, but your method works beautifully.  Thanks again.